# SQL: SUM on Aggregate columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
SELECT
  spend_codes.spend_code,
  SUM(orders.shipping_cost + orders.sales_tax + orders.manual_total + orders.fees) as order_total,
  SUM(ordered_items.fees + ordered_items.price * ordered_items.quantity) as item_total
FROM spend_codeables
LEFT JOIN spend_codes
  ON spend_codeables.spend_code_id = spend_codes.id
LEFT JOIN orders
  ON spend_codeables.spend_codeable_id = orders.id AND spend_codeables.spend_codeable_type = 'App\Order'
LEFT JOIN ordered_items
  ON spend_codeables.spend_codeable_id = ordered_items.id AND spend_codeables.spend_codeable_type = 'App\OrderedItem'
GROUP BY
  spend_codes.spend_code;
```

Which has this result:

```
+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| spend_code   | order_total   | item_total   |
|--------------+---------------+--------------|
| 1230131391   | $362.00       | <null>       |
| A12345       | <null>        | <null>       |
| B29393       | <null>        | $374.28      |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

However, I'd like to add `order_total` and `item_total` in order to get just `total`.

So I'd expect this:

```
+--------------+---------------+
| spend_code   | total         |
|--------------+---------------+
| 1230131391   | $362.00       |
| A12345       | <null>        |
| B29393       | $374.28       |
+--------------+---------------+
```

Doing this did not work:

```
  SUM(orders.shipping_cost + orders.sales_tax + orders.manual_total + orders.fees) +
  SUM(ordered_items.fees + ordered_items.price * ordered_items.quantity) as total
```

Another monkeywrench is that the type of the numbers is `money` not `integer`.

Anyone would be able to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of the 2 sums returns `NULL` then the result of the sum of the sums will also be `NULL` because `NULL + anything` returns `NULL`.

Use `SUM()` only once:

```
SUM(
  orders.shipping_cost + 
  orders.sales_tax + 
  orders.manual_total + 
  orders.fees +
  ordered_items.fees + 
  ordered_items.price * ordered_items.quantity
) as total
```

If any of the columns involved may also be `NULL` use `COALESCE()` like `COALESCE(orders.shipping_cost, 0::money)`

Comment: Is there a way to also do an addition first and then multiply? IE: (o.item_fees + o.item_price) * o.quantity). I just noticed that as an error in my query

Comment: @RizaKhan of course you can apply the logic that you want in the calculation, but since you are using LEFT joins and you may get nulls in some columns use COALESCE() properly. Check my edited answer.

Comment: There is one problem... COALESCE does not work on type `money`

Comment: @RizaKhan check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

you do it in next step using sub query and I used coalesce() for avoid null

```
   with cte as ( SELECT
      spend_codes.spend_code,
      SUM(orders.shipping_cost + orders.sales_tax + orders.manual_total + orders.fees) as order_total,
      SUM(ordered_items.fees + ordered_items.price * ordered_items.quantity) as item_total
    FROM spend_codeables
    LEFT JOIN spend_codes
      ON spend_codeables.spend_code_id = spend_codes.id
    LEFT JOIN orders
      ON spend_codeables.spend_codeable_id = orders.id AND spend_codeables.spend_codeable_type = 'App\Order'
    LEFT JOIN ordered_items
      ON spend_codeables.spend_codeable_id = ordered_items.id AND spend_codeables.spend_codeable_type = 'App\OrderedItem'
    GROUP BY
      spend_codes.spend_code
) select spend_code,coalesce(order_total,0)+coalesce(item_total,0) as total from cte
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you apply the `coalesce` directly to the `sum()`, or use a single `sum` as in the solution from @forpas